# Line Plot in ggplot2 using Multiple data files

Tags: r, ggplot2, line

Object 1:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16026, 16027, 16028, 16029, 
16030, 16031, 16032, 16034, 16035, 16036, 16037, 16038, 16039, 
16040, 16041, 16042, 16043, 16044, 16045, 16046, 16048, 16049, 
16050, 16051, 16052, 16053, 16055, 16056), class = "Date"), Catagory = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("build", 
"client"), class = "factor"), User_Name = c(1L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 12L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L)), .Names = c("Date", "Catagory", 
"User_Name"), row.names = c(NA, 28L), class = "data.frame")
```

Object 2:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(16026, 16027, 16028, 16029, 
16030, 16031, 16032, 16034, 16035, 16036, 16037, 16038, 16039, 
16041, 16042, 16043, 16044, 16045, 16046, 16048, 16049, 16050, 
16051, 16052, 16053, 16055, 16056), class = "Date"), Catagory = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("build", 
"client"), class = "factor"), User_Name = c(1L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("Date", "Catagory", "User_Name"
), row.names = c(NA, 27L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here I want to plot a single line plot where x-axis would denote time and y-axis would denote the variable User_Name. The time data in both the objects is almost same while the User_Name count is different. I was trying to use ggplot2 to use plot my intended graph. but I don't know how use 2 different object file to plot in a single graph in ggplot2.

NOTE: I tried merging the data in one single object. but some data is getting missed due to mismatch of column length mismatch.

EDITED: I figured it out this way

```
ggplot()+geom_line(data=build_9,aes(x=Date,y=User_Name),color="red")+geom_line(data=build_10,aes  (x=Date,y=User_Name),color="blue")
```

I want to add point in each values i.e in each data points in the graph.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to merge here, just add a column for each object(data.frame) to characterize it.

```
obj1$type <- 'obj1'
obj2$type <- 'obj2'
dat <- rbind(obj1,obj2)
```

Then using `ggplot` you can do this:

```
ggplot(dat,aes(x=Date,y=User_Name))+
    geom_point()+
    geom_line(aes(color=type))
```

[image]

Comment: I have done this way ggplot()+geom_line(data=build_9,aes(x=Date,y=User_Name),color="red")+geom_line(data=build_10,aes(x=Date,y=User_Name),color="blue")              .   I need I more modifications. I want to have a point at each data point or values in the data set. How can I do it?

Comment: @user3132179 No. I am using the same object , and ggplot2 split it automatically using color aes. Look at my edit for points.

Comment: ok so u mean to say point is not possible the way I have done it right?

Comment: @user3132179 No I don't mean that. I mean it is simpler to do it the way I did.